# Correctly positioning text on Canvas when scaling

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I am scaling my context and placing text on the canvas. However the scaling throws off the positioning of the text on the canvas, because the X value is scaled, and I'm not sure how to get it centered. Here is my code:

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
let scaleX = 0.5;
const metrics = ctx.measureText(txt);
if (metrics.width > canvas.width) {
  scaleX = canvas.width / metrics.width;
}
const scaleY = this.dimension / lineHeight;
ctx.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillText(txt, canvas.width / 2, 0);
```

If the text being placed is long enough, `scaleX` could be something like `0.2369378483`. In that case, even though `ctx.fillText` places the text at the x value of `canvas.width / 2` it is not centered because it is scaled by `0.2369378483`.

How do I account for this discrepancy when placing the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up equalizing the x position by calculating an inverse scale value:

```
let xPos = canvas.width / 2;
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
const posScale = 1 / scaleX;
xPos = xPos * posScale;
...
ctx.fillText(txt, xPos, 0);
```

This inverted the scale for the x position so it was as if no scale was applied.